# CKQueryOperation with CKQueryCursor causes internal server error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I use a method to fetch all CloudKit entries at the first startup of the app.
This worked fine for a while but recently after the first batch of 100 results I receive following error:

CKError 0x15cdd5d90: "Server Rejected Request" (15/2000); server
message = "Internal server error";

```
 - (void)fetchAllCKEntries{

    if (self.fQueryCursor) {
        fQueryOperation = [[CKQueryOperation alloc]initWithCursor:self.fQueryCursor];

    } else {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];
        CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"FUD" predicate:predicate];
        fQueryOperation = [[CKQueryOperation alloc]initWithQuery:query]; 
    }

    fQueryOperation.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceUserInitiated;

    __block double fCount = 0;

    fQueryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = ^(CKRecord *record) {

        fCount = fCount + 1;
        [self storeFFromCloudKit:record];
    };

    fQueryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = ^(CKQueryCursor *cursor, NSError *operationError) {

        if (operationError) {

            NSLog(@"F query error: %@", operationError.localizedDescription);

        } else if (cursor) {

            NSLog(@"Fetched %.f entires, more coming...",fCount);
            self.fQueryCursor = cursor;
            [self fetchAllCKEntries];

        } else {

            NSLog(@"Fetched %.f entries, done",fCount);
            self.fQueryCursor = cursor;
        }
    };

    [publicDatabase addOperation:fQueryOperation];
}
```

Is this really an internal server error or am I missing something here?

Comment: it works with a different record type, really seems to be an internal error related to one record type...

Comment: Restting the development environment from the dashboard sometimes fixes these

Comment: ok.. seems like I will need to do that, when fetching notification changes I now receive following error: Error code: RESET_NEEDED

Comment: Thanks @Luke the reset of the development environment in the dashboard fixed the issue for me